# How to render blob images from API

Tags: reactjs, api, blob

How can i render a image with address blob:http://painelbahia.oliveirawesley.com.br/d3b242ea-ef0a-469e-8a90-1d598a8daebf that a received from API response using ReactJS ?

Thank you very much!

```
{ this.state.notices.map(notice => 
      <div key={notice._id}>
        {notice.title}
        {notice.subtitle}
        <img src={notice.miniatura} alt="Miniatura" width="300px" height="300px"/>
      </div>

      )}
```

Comment: If your server sends you a string `"blob:http..."` while it should represent an URL, then fix that API. BlobURIs can't be shared.

Comment: Ohhh man I'll fix this so! Thank you very much!